# Is there a way to prevent export wizard from popping up each time i run query with @expert inbuilt in dbeaver?

Tags: oracle, automation, export, dbeaver

I have a query that i run and export multiple times and i have managed to use the @export preprocessing function in dbeaver to prefill the export settings. The annoying thing about it is that althought the settings are prefilled, each time i run the query the wizard shows and i have to click next next next and proceed for the export to commence. How do i get rid of this annoying wizard?

heres a snip of the @export function i used:
`@export {"type": "csv", "producer": {"openNewConnections": "true", "queryRowCount": "true"}, "consumer": {"outputFolder": "C:/Users/dnk/Documents/My_Data_Dumps", "outputFilePattern": "${scriptFilename}_${timestamp}", "outputTimestampPattern": "dd-MM-yyyy"}, "processor": {}}`